# как получить значение стилей не в px а в простых числах

Tags: javascript

я использую такой код,чтобы получить значение `margin-top`:

```
var elt = document.getElementById("l_contant");

var marginTop = window.getComputedStyle(elt, null).getPropertyValue("margin-top");
```

но,я получаю его в px,а надо-бы в обычном числе

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Используйте `parseFloat`

```js
console.log(parseFloat('14.2px'))
```

Comment: Б л а г о д а р ю!

Answer (score 1):

Просто прогоняй результат через parseFloat()